# opencv draw point and line between 2 points

Tags: visual-c++, drawing, opencv

how to draw point and line between 2 points in opencv??? Would like by clicking in image using mouse draw points and connect them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Drawing Functions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) specifically cv::Line

Comment: ... and take note that cvPoint is just the constructor of a CvPoint structure and it doesn't draws anything. To draw a single point(pixel) You should use cvLine with both ends in equal point.

Answer (score 2):

look at the included samples called drawing.py and inpaint.py or their c++ equivalents.
The Sketcher class inside inpaint.py is probably what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Mouse functions in opencv is a real chore.  If it helps, here is my code example of drawing rectangles on video.  Its fully functional so you can just cut and paste the whole thing.  You should be able to pick it apart and see how mouse handling works.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

  #define SSTR( x ) dynamic_cast< std::ostringstream & >(( std::ostringstream() << std::dec << x ) ).str()

using  namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Rect box;
bool drawing_box = false;
struct mousecallbackstruct{
    Mat* src;
    Mat* overlay;
    string windowname;
};
Mat srcoverlay,smallsrcoverlay;




void onMouse(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)  //it seems the only way to use this is by keeping different globals for different windows - meaning you have to set up all thise ahead of time, and keep track of it and not mix/match windows/frames!!  horrible design here.
{
    cout << event;
    mousecallbackstruct mousestruct;
    mousestruct = *((mousecallbackstruct*)param);
    Mat* srcp = mousestruct.src;
    Mat* overlayp = mousestruct.overlay;
    Mat src = *srcp;
    Mat overlay = *overlayp;

    if(!src.data){
        cout <<  "your void * cast didn't work :(\n";
        return;
    }
    switch( event ){
        case CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE: 
            if( drawing_box ){
                box.width = x-box.x;
                box.height = y-box.y;
            }
            break;

        case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:  //start drawing
            drawing_box = true;
            box = cvRect( x, y, 0, 0 );
            break;
        case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:  //double click to clear
            drawing_box = false;
            overlay.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(0));  //clear it
            break;
        case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:  //draw what we created with Lbuttondown
            drawing_box = false;
            if( box.width < 0 ){
                box.x += box.width;
                box.width *= -1;
            }
            if( box.height < 0 ){
                box.y += box.height;
                box.height *= -1;
            }
            rectangle( overlay, Point(box.x, box.y), Point(box.x+box.width,box.y+box.height),CV_RGB(100,200,100),4);  //draw rectangle.  You can change this to line or circle or whatever.  Maybe with the Right mouse button.
            break;
    }
}


void iimshow(mousecallbackstruct* mystructp){  //this is where we add the text/drawing created in the mouse handler to the actual image (since mouse handler events do not line up with the drawing events)

    mousecallbackstruct mystruct = *mystructp;  //custom struct made for the mouse callback - very handy for other functions too
    Mat overlay, src;
    Mat* srcp = mystruct.src;
    Mat* overlayp = mystruct.overlay;
    src = *srcp;                                // yeah, yeah, i use 9 lines where I could use 3, so sue me
    overlay = *overlayp;
    string name = mystruct.windowname;
    Mat added,imageROI;

    try{
        //cout << "tch:" << overlay.rows << "," << src.rows << ";" <<  overlay.cols <<  "," << src.cols << ";" <<  src.channels() <<  "," << overlay.channels() <<"," <<  src.type() <<  "," << overlay.type() << "\n";
        if(overlay.data && overlay.rows == src.rows && overlay.cols == src.cols && overlay.channels() == src.channels()){  //basic error checking
            add(src,overlay,added);
        }else{
           //try to resize it
            imageROI= overlay(Rect(0,0,src.cols,src.rows));
            add(src,imageROI,added);
        }

        imshow(name,added);// the actual draw moment

    }catch(...){  //if resize didn't work then this should catch it
        cout << "Error.  Mismatch:" << overlay.rows << "," << src.rows << ";" <<  overlay.cols <<  "," << src.cols << ";" <<  src.channels() <<  "," << overlay.channels() <<"," <<  src.type() <<  "," << overlay.type() << "\n";
        imshow(name + "overlay",overlay);
        imshow(name+"source",src);
    }

}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
     VideoCapture cap(0); // open the default camera
    if(!cap.isOpened()) { // check if we succeeded
        cout << "NO camera found \n";
        return -1;
    }

    Mat src,smallsrc,overlay;
    cap >> src;  //grab 1 frame to build our preliminary Mats and overlays

    srcoverlay.create(src.rows,src.cols,src.type());  //create overlays
    smallsrcoverlay.create(src.rows,src.cols,src.type());
    srcoverlay.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(0));  //clear it
    smallsrcoverlay.setTo(cv::Scalar::all(0));  //clear it

    namedWindow( "smallsrc", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    namedWindow( "source", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );  //these must be created early for the setmousecallback, AND you have to know what Mats will be using them and not switch them around :(
    moveWindow("smallsrc",2000,100);  //create a small original capture off to the side of screen

    ////////////// for each window/mat that uses a mouse handler, you must create one of these structures for it and pass it into the mouse handler
    mousecallbackstruct srcmousestruct,smallsrcmousestruct;  //these get passed into the mouse callback function.  Hopefully they update their contents automatically for the callback?  :(
    srcmousestruct.overlay = &srcoverlay;  //fill our custom struct
    srcmousestruct.src = &src;
    srcmousestruct.windowname = "source";

    smallsrcmousestruct.overlay = &smallsrcoverlay;  //the small window
    smallsrcmousestruct.src = &smallsrc;
    smallsrcmousestruct.windowname = "smallsrc";

    setMouseCallback(smallsrcmousestruct.windowname, onMouse, (void*)&smallsrcmousestruct); //the actual 'set mouse callback' call
    setMouseCallback(srcmousestruct.windowname, onMouse, (void*)&srcmousestruct);

    for(;;){  //main loop
      /// Load an image
      cap >> src;

      if( !src.data )
      { return -1; }

      resize(src,smallsrc,Size(),.5,.5);  //smaller scale window of original

      overlay = *srcmousestruct.overlay;
      src = *srcmousestruct.src;

      iimshow(&srcmousestruct);  //my imshow replacement.  uses structs
      iimshow(&smallsrcmousestruct);

      if(waitKey(30) == 27) cin.get();  //esc pauses
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```